# Ubuntu Upgrade: How to fix "Failed to fetch"

Tags: upgrade, 22.10, 23.04

Trying to upgrade Ubuntu 22.10 to 23.04 by calling "sudo update-manager -c" repeatedly fails with the following three errors:

```
Failed to fetch http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/base-passwd/base-passwd_3.6.1_amd64.deb Connection failed [IP: 109.202.202.202 80]
Failed to fetch http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice-common_7.5.2-0ubuntu1_all.deb Connection failed [IP: 109.202.202.202 80]
Failed to fetch http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/u/ubuntu-restricted-addons/ubuntu-restricted-addons_28_amd64.deb Connection failed [IP: 109.202.202.202 80]
```

All other packages download successfully. Its just those three packages that block the upgrade. Do you have any ideas how to fix this? Preferably without completely reinstalling?

**Edit:**

Removing all repositories at the GUI ("Software & Updates" app, tab "Other Software") did not fix the issue.

Deleting and recreating `/etc/apt/sources.list` also had no effect.

So any other ideas are very appreciated.

Comment: You have a PPA linking to an "archive" in your sources list. Please remove them and then do the upgrade as those will not exist for a new release

Comment: @Rinzwind Thank you very much for sharing this! Unfortunately removing any archives did not fix the issue.

Comment: @karel Thank you very much for your help! Unfortunately the error persists, even after deleting and recreating `/etc/apt/sources.list` (as described in the link you've provided).

Comment: Try to replace ch by fr in your sources.list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried switching to the main server for downloading Ubuntu updates?

Open "Software & Updates" --> "Ubuntu Software" tab --> "Download from" section --> Select "Main server".

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've tried switching servers before but it didn't had any effect. Today it worked after updating the system. So it looks as if this could have been a bug that got fixed with the update...